# OpenERP 7.0 HR Expenses Module Due Amount Calculation

Tags: odoo

In OpenERP HR Expense module we require some customization, I have added two fields one is advance taken from Company(x_adv) and due amount(x_dueamt).our requirement is calculate due amount (total_amount - x_adv). where and what should i write code.

for Example Employee A took advance from company for project X 500 INR
But his total Expense is 1000 INR. Now we want to calculate due amount 500 INR
automatically (x_dueamt is readonly).

Please Help us .... Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by two ways:

(1) You can write on_change method on `advance taken from company` & `Total expense` so when there will be any change in these two fields you can calculate amount and return the value you calculated for a `due amount` field.

Here is an example,

> ```
> <field name="x_adv" on_change="onchange_amount(x_adv,total_expense)"/>
> <field name="total_expense" on_change="onchange_amount(x_adv,total_expense)"/>
> <field name="due_amount"/>
> ```

In your .py file write on onchange_amount function, this function will be called when there will be any change of `x_adv` & `total_expense`.

```
def onchange_amount(self, cr, uid, ids, x_adv, total_amount, context={}):
    // Your calculation
    value = {'due_amount': calculate_value}
    return {'value': value}
```

This will work fine but there will be a little problem if the resulted field(Here due_amount) is readonly it will not show in client & also in database. So there is a second way to sp;ve your problem.

(2) Make due_amount a field function.

> ```
> def _calculate_due_amount(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
>     res = {}
>     if context is None:
>         context = {}
>     for current_ids in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)[0]
>         // Your calculation
>         res[current_ids] = calculated_amount
>     return res
>
>
>
> 'due_amount': fields.function(_calculate_due_amount, string='Due Amount', help="Due amount of employee.",
>                               store={
>                                      'your_object': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, c={}: ids, ['x_adv', 'total_expense'], 10)
>                                     }),
> ```

This is one of the best suitable way to solve your problem. By function field you can store value in database & also can make field readonly. Hope this works fine for you.